# Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented error when setting csp_nonce_assign_key

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://francis.chabouis.fr/posts/csp-nonce-with-phoenix/) for adding a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) header to the live dashboard route in Phoenix. It works fine until I use a `Map` as the `csp_nonce_assign_key` value instead of an `atom`.

Maps seem to be supported as per the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_dashboard/Phoenix.LiveDashboard.Router.html#live_dashboard/2-options) and it does seem to work when I set the value in my `router.ex` file like this:

```
live_dashboard "/dashboard",
  csp_nonce_assign_key: %{
    img: generate_nonce(),
    style: generate_nonce(),
    script: generate_nonce(),
  }
```

However, it doesn't work if I use a Plug like this:

```
# router.ex

live_dashboard "/dashboard",
  csp_nonce_assign_key: :csp_nonce_value
```

```
# my_plug.ex

def call(conn, _opts) do
  conn
  |> assign(:csp_nonce_value, %{
    img: generate_nonce(),
    style: generate_nonce(),
    script: generate_nonce(),
  })
end
```

When I use the `Plug` version I get the following error: `protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %{img: "fMIOCwnmMfsaOA", script: "m1oNHieWGoYMfw", style: "9EDcaW6JlgcfxQ"} of type Map.`

What I don't understand is why the same error doesn't happen in the first version. PS. I'm new to Elixir, so I'm guessing there's something super obvious I'm missing here.

Comment: Have you got any resolution for the same?

Comment: Nope, still have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. If you're also having this issue try upvoting this question, maybe it will catch someone's attention to help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the [blog post](https://francis.chabouis.fr/posts/csp-nonce-with-phoenix/#edit) with an answer to your question.
To make it short, you need to create 3 different assigns in the Plug, containing the 3 nonces.

Then in the router, you give the name of these 3 assigns, not the nonce values.

in the Plug:

```
  def call(conn, _opts) do
    # a random string is generated
    nonce_1 = generate_nonce()
    nonce_2 = generate_nonce()
    nonce_3 = generate_nonce()

    csp_headers = csp_headers(Application.fetch_env!(:my_app, :app_env), nonce_1, nonce_2, nonce_3)

    conn
    # the nonce is saved in the connection assigns
    |> Plug.Conn.assign(:img_src_nonce, nonce_1)
    |> Plug.Conn.assign(:img_style_nonce, nonce_2)
    |> Plug.Conn.assign(:img_script_nonce, nonce_3)
    |> Phoenix.Controller.put_secure_browser_headers(csp_headers)
  end
```

In the router file

```
live_dashboard("/phoenix-dashboard",
  metrics: Transport.PhoenixDashboardTelemetry,
  csp_nonce_assign_key: %{
    img: :img_src_nonce,
    style: :img_style_nonce,
    script: :img_script_nonce,
  })
```